# RecyclerView inside nestedscrollview with bottom sheet behavior

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

I am making an app that displays post activities of different users like facebook. I have made postList Activity, in which username, his post image and post text will be displayed. Also want to implement like and comment feature in my app. On comment textview, bottomsheet will appear with list of comments of different users.

Problem is that i have used nestedscrollview with bottomsheet behavior. Inside nestedscroll view, there is recycler view.

here is my xml layout of bottomsheet

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/commentList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

This is Post List xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/post_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addNewPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />
```

This is postlist adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

NestedScrollView bottom_sheet;
CoordinatorLayout mainLayout;

private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> posts,NestedScrollView 
bottom_sheet,CoordinatorLayout mainLayout) {
    this.posts = posts;
    this.context = context;
    this.bottom_sheet=bottom_sheet;
    this.mainLayout=mainLayout;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

           mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottom_sheet);

    mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            switch (newState) {
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED: {
                }
                break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED: {
                }
                break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                    break;
                case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                    break;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

        }
    });

    holder.comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            } else {
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }
        }
    });


}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return posts.size();
}
```

}

And this is the adapter for comments

```
public class CommentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentViewHolder> {

Context context;

public CommentAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public CommentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment_layout, parent, false);
    CommentViewHolder viewHolder = new CommentViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CommentViewHolder holder, int position) {

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    commentReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Comments");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    uId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    final Comment comment = comments.get(position);

    holder.commentUName.setText("Numrah");
    holder.commentText.setText("hello");

    holder.addCommentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "comment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return comments.size();
}
}
```

PostList Activity

public class PostList extends AppCompatActivity {

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<Post> posts;
CustomAdapter customAdapter;
FloatingActionButton addPost;
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference postReference;
DatabaseReference likeReference;
DatabaseReference commentReference;
NestedScrollView bottomSheet;
CoordinatorLayout mainLayout;
private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
RecyclerView commentRecyclerView;
ArrayList<Comment> comments;
CommentAdapter commentAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_list);

    bottomSheet = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet1);
    mainLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    commentRecyclerView=bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.commentList);
    comments = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    //layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
    commentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    commentRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    commentAdapter = new CommentAdapter(this, comments);
    commentRecyclerView.setAdapter(commentAdapter);

    firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    postReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Post");
    likeReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Likes");
    commentReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Comments");

    posts = new ArrayList<>();
    addPost = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addNewPost);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.post_list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, posts, bottomSheet, mainLayout);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);



    addPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(PostList.this, AddPost.class));

        }
    });

    postReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            posts.add(post);
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            int indexOfItem = posts.indexOf(post);
            if (indexOfItem >= 0) {
                posts.set(indexOfItem, post);

            }
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    if (mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {

        super.onBackPressed();

    } else {
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you please be precise about what you want ?? and what is happening currently ??

Comment: i want to open bottomsheet when user clicked on comment.But in bottomsheet layout file i have nestedscroll view with bottomsheet behavior.Inside of it there is a recycler view.But when bottomsheet is opens,nothing is displaying in recycler view

Comment: post your post_list activity..please..

Comment: @SantanuSur Posted

Comment: you dont have value in your `commentAdapter` `comment` is `empty arrayList` @Numrah

Comment: Yes.But i was giving hardcoded value in commentAdapter for checking purpose.But that was not showing as well.

Comment: you mean "Numrah" and "hello" @Numrah ??

Comment: @SantanuSur Yes

Comment: updated the answer please check and update if recyclerView shows 5 items now.. @Numrah

Comment: giving error on 5.i returned 1 and it works.

Comment: it should not give error with `5` but if you understood the point thats enough :) @Numrah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your arraylist `comments` is empty ( **comments.size() is 0** ) the `getItemCount()` of your `CommentAdapter` is returning `0` . Hence zero rows will be inflated and your recyclerView would be blank. So your test case wont be executed  To execute your test case try this in your **CommentAdapter** :-

```
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5; // returning static no of items
     }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my mistake.Now it works.Thanks alot :)